# How can I write both an array of int and array of char to a file

Tags: c, io

Im trying to write and read an array of ints in a binary file. The two functions look like this, more or less.

#### savefunction

```
int numbers[6]={0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1};
FILE *file;
if(file=fopen(filename, "wb")==NULL)
{
    printf("Something went wrong reading %s\n", filename);
    return 0;
}
else
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
        fprintf(file, "%d", numbers[i]);
}
fclose(file);
```

#### loadfunction

```
FILE *saved_data;
int errors=0;
if((saved_data=fopen(filename, "rb"))==NULL)
    errors++;
else
{
    fread(first, sizeof(int), 1, saved_data);
    fread(second, sizeof(int), 1, saved_data);
    fread(third, sizeof(int), 1, saved_data);
    fread(fourth, sizeof(int), 1, saved_data);
    fread(fifth, sizeof(int), 1, saved_data);
    fread(sixt, sizeof(int), 1, saved_data);
}
fclose(saved_data);
```

Now when I debug the program the debugger tells me that the first element is the following

```
(gdb) print first
$1 = (int *) 0x7fff5fbff968
(gdb) print *first
$2 = 858993200
```

I can't understand this. The file when opening with editor says ***023301***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complementary function of `fread` is `fwrite`, not `fprintf`. What you're doing with `fprintf` is putting the integers into the file as text, not as binary.

Also, make sure you pass a pointer to `fread`, not an integer. You don't show the declarations of `first`, `second`, and so on, but if you've declared something like

```
int first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixt;
```

then you'll need to use code like

```
fread(&first, sizeof(int), 1, saved_data);
```

rather than

```
fread(first, sizeof(int), 1, saved_data);
```

Since your integers are already in an array, you can just write the array in one go with

```
fwrite(numbers, sizeof(int), 6, file);
```

and avoid the `for` loop altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no objections to keeping your file as text all the way through, alter your fopen to open as text, and alter your read statements to read them in as text.  As it stands, it looks like you are inconsistently treating your file as text in one part, then as binary in another, which can corrupt it.

Comment: You'll need delimiters or something if you stay with all-text. Unless you know all your integers will be single-digit, there's no way to tell that your file doesn't contain the single number 23,301. :)

Comment: Agreed.  I assumed the OP knew this, but I should not have made that assumption.  Good catch.