# Reading and writing from/to .bin file in C

Tags: c

```
pInput = fopen("input.bin", "w+b");
if (pInput == NULL)
{
    return(-1);
    MyLogs(szError);
}

printf("Enter 'x': "); scanf("%lf", &x);

fwrite(&a, sizeof(double), 1, pInput);
fwrite(&x, sizeof(double), 1, pInput);
fwrite(&b, sizeof(double), 1, pInput);

fseek(pInput, 0, SEEK_SET);

fread(&a, sizeof(double), 1, pInput);
fread(&x, sizeof(double), 1, pInput);
fread(&b, sizeof(double), 1, pInput);
fclose(pInput);

char buff[100];
snprintf(buff, 99, "Parameter file 'input.bin' opened. X = %.3lf, a = %.0lf, b = %.0lf.", x, a, b);

MyLogs(buff);

dResult = x / a - 1 / (a * 6) * log10(a + b*exp(6 * x));
```

I had to write the program (*for my homework using freed(), fwrite(), ftell(), fseek()* ), which writes to binary some data and then reads it to calculate expression. I have a question. **Do I have to write three fwrite() s and three freed() s?** Or can I do this in one function call? Is there a perfect way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423453/how-can-i-write-both-an-array-of-int-and-array-of-char-to-a-file) is you answer about "how to write it better"
Just use an array instead of one by one parameters.
About the `.bin` file this is not an extension, the same solution works with `.txt` and even no extension.